# Estoy usando bun y quiero crear una bd con sqlite pero el problema es que me salta un error en .db.serialize()

Tags: typescript, sqlite

En db.serialize() me salta el siguiente error: "Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'".
No entiendo porque me sale ese error.

```
import { Database } from "bun:sqlite";

const db: Database = new Database("mydb.sqlite", { create: true });

db.serialize(() => {
    db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tasks (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, description TEXT, done BOOLEAN)');
});

export default db;
```

Comment: Estas en SO en español.. asi que por favor, traduci tu pregunta, y de paso, explica que es esto, porque no se entiende absolutamente nada...